# Taking dynamic number of inputs from the same line

Tags: python

How can we take dynamic number of inputs from the same line? For example, if `N` is my number of inputs, and if `N = 3`, then how can I take in 3 different inputs, all separated by spaces, and store them into 3 different variables?

Now, I know how to take inputs from the same line, provided I know the value of `N` beforehand. I do so using the following code if my number of inputs are 3, and assign them to variables a, b and c respectively:

```
a,b,c = map(int,raw_input().split())
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how I could use this code for assigning dynamic number of inputs to equal number of variables.

Comment: You don't know how many items are on that line? Have you tried just keeping the items in a list?

Comment: Is there a reason that you need them as separate variables (hint: very unlikely that there is)? Otherwise it's probably better to keep them in a list or another data structure more suited for the task.

Comment: @hlt The number of items on that line would be determined by the user. So I can't seem to figure out how I can assign those variable number of items into equal number of variables.

Comment: @RogerFan Yes, I do need them stored inside unique variables.

Comment: **You can't**. There is ***no*** reliable way to dynamically create (local) variables. Even `exec` fails most of the time (especially in python3 where it's not a statement). If you don't know `N` then just use a list. If you don't want to use indices use a dictionary, then instead of `variableX` you can use `the_dict['variableX']` and you are done.

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi *"I do need them stored inside unique variables"* - that is almost certainly incorrect.

Comment: I wasn't aware something like this wasn't possible in Python. Storing my inputs inside a list seems to be a feasible solution for my problem.

Comment: How could you assign a `dynamic number of (...) variables`? How could you access to these afterward? How would you know their names? their count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about something like storing the items in a list and processing them individually?

```
list_of_input = map(int,raw_input().split())

print "you input:"
for i,input_val in enumerate(list_of_input):
    print "item %d: %d:" % (i, input_val)

    if input_val < 5:
        pass   # do something for certain items
    elif input_val > 10:
        pass   # do something else for other items
    else: 
        pass   # etc
```

and if you are dead set on having "unique" string variable names for each input (even though you get this same behavior from a numeric list index which is more robust, general, faster and simpler than the following suggestion):

```
var_names = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
named_lookup = dict(zip(var_names, list_of_input))

print named_lookup["c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[]
mat=[]
n=int(input(""))
for i in range(0,n):
    mat=[int(i) for i in input().split()]  
    l.append(mat)
print(l)
```